# Saving Array In Activity

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` where names are inputed via a `EditText` box and then they get saved into an `Array` and then displayed in a `ListView` where there is also a `Button` that will appear where they can remove it.

Once the correct names have been added they are then passed to the next `Activity` by a `Button` `Intent` to populate a `String`. On the next `Activity` there is a button where they can go back to the previous `Activity` to add more names or remove.

The problem is when they go back to the previous `Activity` the `Array` is empty so I need a way to save the `Array` even when the `Activity` has been left.

`ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>();`

Button to add to the `Array` is below:

```
Button confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText playername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userinput);
        playerList.add(playername.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        playername.setText("");
    }
});
```

Comment: send me invitation for chat ASAP i am leaving office in 5 mins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Bundle` to save your array on `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of activity

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html
2. [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

#### Update

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
    outState.putStringArrayList("Playlist", playerList );

   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }
```

Now to take value

```
    @Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    playerList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("Playlist");

}
```

Comment: Not sure how to implement that can you help me out :)

Comment: you want to join me in a chat?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using a `Bundle` (which is not always flexible enough) is to use a **custom Application class**. You need to define it in your manifest (application name)

```
<application android:name="<package>.MyApplication" ..... />
```

Write the custom class like that:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private List<String> data;

    public void storeData(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

The good thing with this way is that it allows you all kind of customisation on methods, type of data you can store, etc. Also, you don't need to pass the data between activities, it will always be available and will never be lost as long as the application is active.

From any activity, you can save your data using:

```
final List<String> myData = new ArrayList<String>();
// ... populate myData ...
((MyApplication) getApplication()).storeData(myData);
```

And when you need it:

```
((MyApplication) getApplication()).getData();
```

In fact, I usually put in my custom application everything I want to be able to access from multiple activities.

Comment: I was about to post the same reply :)

Comment: @Matt : This easier way then Saving State of Activity

Comment: @MohitSharma that does look a nice way of doing things can one of you join me in a chat?

Comment: @Guillaume can you come back into the chat room?

Comment: Nope sorry, the chat feature is blocked from my work place :(