# Do I use onSaveInstancestate or SQLite to save user input in ArrayList of custom object when switching activities

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, store

I've been trying and searching how to store user input in an ArrayList of custom object. I've tried **onSaveInstancestate** with my custom object implement **Parcelable**.
I have an activity for user input, this input goes into my custom object and then put into an ArrayList. I pass the arrayList from one activity to the other where i have an Listview that i wanna fill with the objects from my ArrayList. This all works fine but, when i go back to the activity to give new input it replaces the old. So it doesnt save the objects in the arrayList. Am I using the wrong tool and should I use SQLite instead? Or maybe, because I'm new to coding, i have missed something obvious that prevents it from working correctly.

I thought this "[Saving Array In Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851361/saving-array-in-activity)" was going to be helpful so I used it but because Im not using a string object but my own object it might not for me?

Comment: Would you like to save the information even after the app is closed, or only for the life-cycle of the application? If it's the former, could you please include the code for the model class that populates your `ArrayList` in your question?

Comment: You are right with you implementation but make sure you added code in onRestoreInstanceState also to refill old data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the longevity/importance of the data itself, if it'll be used for a long period of time, then you should use SQLite.

From what you're saying, `onSaveInstancestate` sounds like the correct way for you to go. You can still make use of your own custom Object granted that object - granted that it implements `android.os.Parcelable`.